# Build and install golang project with some internal packages

Tags: go

I have following golang project structure:

```
- go-projects
  - src
    - github.com
      - user
        - my-project
          - pack
            - pack.go
          - main.go
```

my `GOPATH` is:

`export GOPATH=/home/user/go-projects`

I'm trying to call functions from `pack` package in `main.go` file and trying to build this project with:

`cd my-project
go build && go-install`

There is no any output, and also there is no `bin` directory anywhere. What i did wrong?

**UPD** This problem was solved. accidently missunderstood file content of main.go and pack.go. But now there is another problem.

How to build correctly this program. When i'm trying to execute go build in `/home/user/go-projects/src/github.com/user/my-project` i'm getting following erros:

```
main.go:4:8: cannot find package "github.com/user/pack" in any of:
    /home/user/Downloads/go/src/pkg/github.com/user/pack (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/go-projects/src/github.com/user/pack (from $GOPATH)
```

Thank you

Comment: you don't need `go build`, `go install` runs that as a preliminary step, but it will create a binary if you're in a main package, which could be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may be convenient to let the tools infer the package from the current working directory, it doesn't work for much more than a simple `main` package. Get used to referencing packages by their full import path, and you'll save yourself other problems down the line.

```
go install github.com/user/pack
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes into `$GOPATH/bin/my-project`, if you wanna test it right away just use `go run main.go`

Comment: thank for the answer, but: 1. i have $GOPATH/bin/ directory but it's empty 2. tried go run main.go i'm getting cannot run non main file, but there is simple hello world - https://gist.github.com/0xAX/7e077f35defc3631356a